# Leaking Metal Gutters

Tags: gutters, rust, metal-roof

The screws attaching the gutters to the metal awning have rusted. They don't move when I turn them. There is also some white powder substance on the gutters and the metal awning. They are leaking in a few places and moldy. Pressure Washing does nothing so I guess I need a metal brush?

I want to clean them up and paint them with something (?) for protection. Will just caulking be enough to stop the leaks since I can't remove the screws?

[image: Gutter and Awning]

[image: Where Gutter is attached to Awning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white powder may be [chalking paint](https://www.dunnedwards.com/explore/how-to/paint-problem-solver/chalking/) (insignificant cosmetic change) or aluminum corrosion. Aluminum builds up a thin, transparent, oxide film that protects it, but when continually exposed to water, with that surface oxide broken by rusty screws, and with [galvanic corrosion](https://www.quora.com/During-galvanic-corrosion-what-exactly-does-iron-do-to-aluminum-to-speed-up-the-corroding-of-aluminum), it *does* corrode. (This is a greater problem near salt water, and the reason that aluminum and magnesium wheels require coatings to resist road salt.)

The screw heads *can* be removed with an abrasive wheel in a drill or high-speed rotary tool, and, as each is removed, a new **stainless steel** screw can be put in next to the old hole to prevent the gutter from sagging.

Clean up the rust stains and corrosion with a hand wire brush, such as [this from Lowe's](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Warner-Stainless-Steel-Coarse-Wire-Brush/3166527) (rotary wire brushes shed bits of wire, which later rust). There are also chemicals (e.g., [this from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004WAENYS)) for badly corroded areas, but be sure to *thoroughly* rinse to prevent further corrosion.

Apply aluminum primer (e.g., [this from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rust-Oleum-Professional-15-oz-Flat-White-Interior-Exterior-Aluminum-Primer-Spray-254170/202531910)) and paint as needed.

*Note:* Items mentioned above are just examples, not recommendations.